# Is the eladrin missing racial features?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, racial-traits, eladrin

According to ["Unearthed Arcana: Eladrin & Gith"](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Eladrin-Gith.pdf), the playable race eladrin doesn't have the racial features [Trance and Fey Ancestry](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Elf#content) like elves do.

I can understand this choice from a game balance perspective, but from a narrative design perspective it doesn't seem to make much sense that a race that is *literally* from the Feywild does *not* have fey ancestry!

Is there an explanation for this, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> At your DM’s option, you can select eladrin as the subrace for an
>   elf character, instead of one of the  elf subraces in the  Player’s
>   Handbook. (same UA article)

> Members of a subrace have the traits of the parent race in addition to
>   the traits specified for their subrace. (PHB 17)

The eladrin traits are added to the traits of the base race (elf).